# get variable of new line into Text(h2)

Tags: javascript, newline, h2, var

So,I have a problem with writing some text(h2) with new line,I created the new line by '\n'.It writes it right into the console,but as h2 element it writes it in one line. 
Code :

```html
     <h2 id="T4"></h2>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    
      var TEST = 'a' + '\n' + 'b'
      console.log(TEST)
    
    document.getElementById("T4").innerHTML = TEST
    </script>
```

Comment: PS : thanks for every reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the HTML special line break tag `<br/>` like this:

```html
     <h2 id="T4"></h2>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    
      var TEST = 'a' + '<br/>' + 'b'
      console.log(TEST)
    
    document.getElementById("T4").innerHTML = TEST
    </script>
```

Comment: Thx.I´ve done it with the help of a list now,but for the layout I think it will be good sometimes.How ever,thanks for all.

Comment: You're welcome! Btw you could always accept the answer if it helped ;)